# Oracle SQL Count Grouping by without repeating records in previous days

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum, grouping

I need to count the distinct WO grouping by day, but not counting the WO that were already in previous days. And sum the LABOR column grouping by day also.

SAMPLE:

```
DAY   WO     LABOR
6   379157    3
9   379157    5
10  379404    8
10  379362    8
19  386118    10
24  386547    2
25  388711    8
25  386547    5
30  386547    1
```

RESULTS

```
DAY   WO    LABOR
6      1    3
9      0    5
10     2    16
19     1    10
24     1    2
25     1    13
30     0    1
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You should really ask one question at a time, not two of them.

Comment: OK, Thanks. The question is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query with `LAG`. The idea is to see whether there is an older entry for a wo and only count it in case there is none.

```
select day, count(case when prev_day is null then 1 end) as wos, sum(labor) as labor
from
(
  select mytable.*, lag(day) over (partition by wo order by day) as prev_day
  from mytable
) 
group by day
order by day;
```

(In case there can be multiple entries per wo and day, you'd have to alter the query slightly. One way would be: `partition by wo order by day, rowid`.)

Comment: Could write `count(*) - count(prev_day)` instead of `count(case when prev_day is null then 1 end)`. Don't know which version will give best results from the query optimizer, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using row_number (since we only want to count the first instance of each wo across all days, per day):

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 6 DAY, 379157 wo, 3 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 9 DAY, 379157 wo, 5 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10 DAY, 379404 wo, 8 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10 DAY, 379362 wo, 8 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 19 DAY, 386118 wo, 10 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 24 DAY, 386547 wo, 2 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 25 DAY, 388711 wo, 8 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 25 DAY, 386547 wo, 5 labor FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 30 DAY, 386547 wo, 1 labor FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking data in "your_table" - see the main SQL below:
SELECT DAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) wo,
       SUM(labor) labor
FROM   (SELECT DAY,
               wo,
               labor,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY wo ORDER BY DAY) rn
        FROM   your_table)
GROUP BY DAY
ORDER BY DAY;

       DAY         WO      LABOR
---------- ---------- ----------
         6          1          3
         9          0          5
        10          2         16
        19          1         10
        24          1          2
        25          1         13
        30          0          1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should GROUP BY WO, and retrieve the MIN day that that WO occurred in as one subquery. The former is essentially is a re-statement of your first requirement. Instead of looking at the WO and trying to exclude WO that appeared on previous days, it can be thought of as "a WO should really only be valid the first time it's seen on any day == the value of WO and the first day (min day) it appeared on"

Then this data set should be joined with another data set that is the sum of the labor on all the days.

Because there are going to be more days in the subquery that sums the labor (there'll be one day for every day that appears in the source) but not necessarily as many days coming out of the query that selects the min day per wo, the query with the more days should serve as the left hand side of a left join

```
SELECT
  labors.day, count(wo), min(sumlabor)
FROM
(
  SELECT day, sum(labor) as sumlabor FROM t GROUP BY day
) labors
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT wo, min(day) as day FROM t GROUP BY wo
) wos
ON 
  wos.day = labors.day

GROUP BY 
  labors.day
```

Hopefully the explanation of how I thought about your problem, and how I then wrote a query from it, will help you think about similar problems in the future - sometimes it's easier to turn logic on its head/state it another way, before writing a query from it

Comment: Most elegant solution would be to use `LAG` function since you done need to join

Comment: Feel free to write a LAG solution then; I write these queries out of my head, on an iPhone and I generally prefer to test things that involve the analytics that I use least often (lag being one of them) - sqlfiddle is a bitch on an iphone. Using "more regular" sql also has the advantage that it's easier to work out for people with only a passing familiarity with SQL, so it could be regarded as a "simple solution" from a learning/maintainability point of view - Kaizen says "go for the simple solution, not the perfect one"

Comment: upvoted on the solution and Kaizen quote :) , but can't agree more with a generic solution.

Comment: `I write these queries out of my head,` -Everyone does so. I mean i have not seen anyone who does query without thinking(not using head) :-))

Comment: Thanks! While it's quite specific, and maybe not helpful to opther people who visit this question in future (unless theyre a new dev responsible for maintaining this system, and reach this query and think "whuut", I suppose one other advantage of avoiding analytics is that when the boss decides he's sick of paying oracle license and wants to move to mysql, it'll carry on working ;)

Comment: @xing - yeah, true, but I think you know what I meant - I mean i write them on an iphone, directly into stackoverflow, with no testing/debugging, rather than  writing them into Toad after building a test table from the sample data and running as I go to check stuff.. I don't use LAG often, so it's not something I'd feel comfortable just blatting down without trying..

Comment: @CaiusJard There is a way to communicate your point and guess how you communicated is atleast not looking good to me.. Good luck,.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's a compliment or a criticism, and of what, but if you think the answer can be improved on, I welcome you to suggest an edit or write your own answer..

Comment: I am very grateful for your help @Caius Jard. Do you think there is a way to do it without the join?, I have to repeat the subquery to obtain t table and it is a little big query.

Comment: Does it give a particular performance problem that you think can be avoided by not using a join?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it works

```
select COUNT(tbl1.wo), sum(tbl1.labor) FROM Table_Name tbl1
where tbl1.wo not in (SELECT tbl2.wo from Table_Name tbl2 WHERE tbl2.day < tbl1.day)
group by tbl1.day
```

Comment: It's missing a column, for starters.. And it will probably also drop those days like day 30, where the value of wo appears in an earlier day (and there arent' any other unique WO on that day)?

Comment: You are right @ Caius Jard. This query doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the given set of data:

```
SELECT day ,SUM( CASE WHEN t>0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) wo, SUM(labor) labor    
FROM  (
        SELECT a.day ,a.wo-LAG(a.wo,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY a.wo ) AS  t,labor FROM  
     my_test a )

GROUP BY  day
ORDER BY day
```